# What is the advantage of using module instead of source()$value in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like someone to explain to me the advantage of using the so-called "module" instead of the source(...)$value in shiny app. I have read the article several times at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html and I am not convinced that it is worth trying to understand this article to change my app, which are all source(...)$value . Sometimes I wonder if some of the things I try to do don't work out due to some limitation of "souce (...)$value".
Thanks.

Comment: One advantage of modules is that they allow you so scope input/output id's under the module's namespace.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by `source(...)$value` ... the "value" of a `source`'d script is the last expression in the script, but since the contents all were loaded into the environment as a side-effect, it's redundant. What `$value`? (I agree with @SmokeyShakers, the advantage for me is in namespace-control. It's also analogous to a "function" in basic R, since you can instantiate the same module multiple times without fear of id collision.)

Comment: @r2evans IIRC, In order to use `source` in a shiny input, you need to specify `$value` or `[[1]]`

Comment: Do you have a reference for that assumption? It defies the normal execution of `source` (which operates on side-effect), and I cannot find a reference on shiny.rstudio.com that includes `source(...)$value`. In fact, https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html mentions the use of `source` in many locations of the `server` context, and none of them use `$value`.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the `souce (...)$value` is excellent way to structure you app and is really helpful when you have a big app with a lot of code. But you cannot reuse the code, since you variable names will collide.

If you want to reuse the same code, you should consider modules. When you have some part of your app that is exactly the same but with different data or some other parameter - that is when you want to use modules. For example I just build a dashboard with two different tabs where the only difference was that one tab was for Austria and the second tab only for Vienna. That was a perfect use case for modules.

Comment: Now, finally, I managed to understand the purpose of the modules in shiny. Short, objective and brilliant answer. Thank you!